# Verificar se o programa está sendo executado no Windows

Tags: java

Boa noite.

Gostaria de saber se poderiam me dar um exemplo EM JAVA de como verificar se meu programa *FEITO EM JAVA* está sendo executado no Windows.

Aproveitando o tópico, gostaria de saber também como eu executo um comando no CMD *USANDO O JAVA* caso ele esteja rodando o programa no Windows. É comum que o cmd do windows não reconheça acentos, mas basta digitar o comando "`chcp 65001`" que ele reconhece...

Resumindo, gostaria de verificar se o usuário executou o programa *FEITO EM JAVA* no windows e se sim executar o comando *EM JAVA* "`chcp 65001`".

Comment: Lucas, não há nenhuma duvida relativa a java na sua pergunta. Essa tag não faz sentido nela.

Comment: Eu coloquei Java, pois quero um exemplo em Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar as propriedades do sistema `os.name`, `os.version` e `os.arch`. Elas estão documentadas [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Veja um código bem simples:

```
class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.version"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch"));
    }
}
```

Eis a saída dele no meu notebook:

```
Windows 8.1
6.3
amd64
```

Coloquei ele também no [ideone](https://ideone.com/lSnJh1). Eis a saída lá:

```
Linux
3.16.0-4-amd64
amd64
```

Para executar o `chcp 65001`, você pode usar o método [`Runtime.exec(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TrocaAcentos {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /k chcp 65001");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Putz Victor. Show de bola. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Victor. Seria possível eu verificar se o cmd esta aberto e executar o comando apenas se o cmd estiver aberto?
Estou fazendo alguns exercícios e o professor ira corrigir, mas agora penso que ele pode talvez estar usando alguma IDE ou algum editor de texto com um plugin de terminal como o VSCode por exemplo, pra testar o código. Neste caso o comando faz-se inútil.

Comment: @Lucas Isso é bem mais difícil. Recomendo neste caso você simplesmente peguntar para o professor onde é que ele vai rodar isso. Decerto que o objetivo do exercício não é ficar batendo cabeça sobre como mostrar caracteres acentuados na saída, então você nem deveria estar se preocupando muito com isso.

Comment: Na verdade eu irei fazer uma prova pra ficar dispensando de algumas matérias por pró eficiência, uma das atividades é construir programas de nível organizacional. Eu venho do C# e algumas coisas em Java estão vagas ainda.

Answer (score 3):

> Respondi essa pergunta quando tinha a tag [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).

Esse código verifica se o notepad está aberto, se estiver ele executa o comando `chcp 65001`:

```
@echo off
set programa=notepad.exe

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %programa%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%programa%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo O %programa% esta aberto.
    chcp 65001
) else (
    echo O %programa% nao esta aberto.
)

pause > nul
```

Comment: Valeu brow. Mas gostaria de algo em Java. Neste caso seu código não me ajuda muito, mas muito obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Comment: @Lucas salva num .bat e executa [**via Runtime.exec()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616014/5524514). Fora disso não é possivel fazer isso nativamente no java.

Comment: Você tinha colocado a tag `cmd`...

Comment: LaércioLopes foi o @Articuno que mudou a tag, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado!

Comment: @Lucas mudei porque a duvida era aplicavel a tag, sua pergunta é que não está muito clara. A resposta atende muito bem ao que está escrito na pergunta, se não é bem sua duvida, edite e seja mais especifico na explicação.

Comment: @Articuno Mais clara que aquilo? oO Qual foi sua duvida? Enfim, a duvida ja foi esclarecida, você disse que não era possível fazer isso, mas o Victor mostrou como fazer. De qualquer forma obrigado.